# Location of destructors in elf files: not where it should be?

Tags: c, gcc, destructor, elf

I register a token destructor function with

```
static void cleanup __attribute__ ((destructor));
```

The function just prints a debug message; the token program runs fine (main() just prints another message; token function prints upon exit).

When I look at the file with

```
nm ./a.out,
```

I see:

```
08049f10 d __DTOR_END__

08049f0c d __DTOR_LIST__
```

However, the token destructor function's address should be at `0x08049f10` - an address which contains 0, indicating end of destructor list, as I can check using:

```
objdump -s ./a.out
```

At `0x08049f0c`, I see `0xffffffff`, as is expected for this location. It is my understanding that what I see in the elf file would mean that no destructor was registered; but it is executed with one.

If someone could explain, I'd appreciate. Is this part of the security suite to prevent inserting malicious destructors? How does the compiler keep track of the destructors' addresses?

My system:

- Ubuntu 12.04.
- elf32-i386
- Kernel: 3.2.0-30-generic-pae
- gcc version: 4.6.3

Comment: I don't know how to fix the layout issue: the bold-faced attribute (similar later in the nm p/o) is actually attribute with 2 leading and trailing _.

Comment: Yeah, the formatting there looked weird; could it be some unprintable character? (In the meantime, I tried to fix it up; does that look right?)

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks. I have noticed before that submitting on SO from my iPhone produces incorrect layout. Maybe that was it.

Comment: Can you search on Meta? There might be a question there about it.

Comment: Will do. Has bugged me for a while. Appreciate pointing it out.

Comment: If you don't find one, then it might be worth posting a question there.

Comment: The good news is: C does not have destructors, so you can safely ignore them, even if the linker happens to pull them in. (it will probably be just empty sections)

Comment: @wildplasser: :) Shouldn't be empty though if you explicitly register one, which additionally executes...

Comment: Just ignore it. If it exists and is non-empty, it belongs to the implemntation. (could be the way how atexit() functions are implemented.) if it is outside main(), it is not your business. I repeat: C has no destructors. Leave them alone, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: GCC does provide support for constructors and destructors in C - see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you care? I might make your own linker script if it matters that much !

Answer (score 0):

**DTOR_LIST** is the start of a table of desctructors. Have a look which section it is in (probably .dtors):

```
~> objdump -t test | grep DTOR_LIST
0000000000600728 l     O .dtors 0000000000000000              __DTOR_LIST__
```

Then dump that section with readelf (or whatever):

```
~> readelf --hex-dump=.dtors test

Hex dump of section '.dtors':
  0x00600728 ffffffff ffffffff 1c054000 00000000 ..........@.....
  0x00600738 00000000 00000000                   ........
```

Which in my test case contains a couple of presumably -1, a real pointer, and then zero termination.